# Installing Rcpp package in R 2.15.0

Tags: r, installation, rcpp

I have a problem installing "Rcpp" package in R. The install command have worked for all packages but not for this one. The R error is :

package ‘Rcpp’ is not available (for R version 2.15.0)

I am using windows Vista.Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As can be seen on the [CRAN status page for Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html), it now depends on R (>= 2.15.1).

So you either update R from 2.15.0 to 2.15.1 (which is not a bad idea), or you can try to install an older Rcpp version such as 0.9.10 which will work with R 2.15.0.

Comment: It seems it uses R 3.0 now and I don't want to upgrade. What can I do now?

Comment: You could do one of two things: i) use an older release, or ii) download the current one and install it locally after editing DESCRIPTION and by installing without vignettes.